# "Views added to a FragmentContainerView must be associated with a Fragment" with android Nav Component

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation

When nav component switches to a fragment, I get this "Views added to a FragmentContainerView must be associated with a Fragment" crash.  What causes this?

Answer (score 45):

I didn't see this mentioned anywhere and it took a while to figure out but in this case, I was trying to set up a old legacy fragment while migrating to the nav arch component.

The reason was in the frag's `onCreateView`, the inflate looked like:

```kotlin
layoutView = inflater.inflate( R.layout.home, container, false );
```

The last argument automatically attaches the view to the container.  This works fine in old style fragments and activities.  It does not work with the nav arch component because the root container is a `FragmentContainerView` which only allows fragments to be attached to it.

Setting the last argument to false makes it work properly.

Comment: There's [a few things that Fragments do before attaching the view](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev:fragment/fragment/src/main/java/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentStateManager.java;l=490-497), so using `true` there breaks a number of things even when not using `FragmentContainerView`, this just being the most obvious one.

Comment: It looks like if you don't specify the attachToRoot for inflation that happens.
this fixes it ->  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_fragment, container, false)

Answer (score 1):

Just replace your **onViewCreated** method.

```
class MyFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(  inflater: LayoutInflater,container: ViewGroup?,  savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_post,container,false) 
    }
}
```

Comment: To add to this answer, the important part is the `false` value being passed as the 3rd argument to the `inflate()` method. Adding this boolean fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with `lifeCycleScope`, make sure you launch and run the block at least in `Lifecycle.State.STARTED` state.