# Views added to a FragmentContainerView must be associated with a Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-navigation-graph

Due to difficulties with the implementation of the back button in the toolbar between two fragments, I decided to start acquaintance with Navigation Graph. But I get an error

`Views added to a FragmentContainerView must be associated with a Fragment. View android.widget.RelativeLayout{...} is not associated with a Fragment.`

This is .xml file with `nav_host_fragment`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout ...
    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"
        app:defaultNavHost="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorBlack"
            android:clickable="@{viewModel.isSearching ? false : true}"
            android:focusable="@{viewModel.isSearching ? false : true}">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recent_recyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:background="@color/colorBlack"
                tools:itemCount="10"
                tools:listitem="@layout/search_user_layout" />

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/search_recyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:background="@color/colorBlack"
                android:visibility="gone"
                tools:itemCount="10"
                tools:listitem="@layout/search_user_layout" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/loading"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:indeterminate="true"
                android:visibility="@{viewModel.isSearching ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </fragment>
</layout>
```

Is it possible to fix it?

Comment: Why are you adding other views within your `<fragment>` tag instead of outside of the `<fragment>` tag?

Comment: Thank you for comment. I do this because if I take `<fragment>` out, I get an error `Only one layout element with 1 view child is allowed`

Comment: And also if I put `<fragment>` inside `<RelativeLayout>` I get an error `View androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView{...} is not associated with a Fragment`

Comment: I think you need to decide what views should be part of your activity (i.e., the one with the NavHostFragment) and what should be the views inflated when you go to a specific fragment (which looks like everything currently inside your `<fragment>` tag) - that should all be a separate layout file.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62010915/views-added-to-a-fragmentcontainerview-must-be-associated-with-a-fragment-with

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check your Fragment's `onCreateView()` Layout inflate . Make sure to set **attachToRoot** false

`inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false)`

It's works for me.